# How to get a reference of callback in anonymous callback function in Javascript

Tags: typescript, callback, reference

[Not Relevant]
My question becomes when I'm currently developing and game with a cocos creator game engine that uses Typescript. 
[Relevant]
I have the next code:

```
    this.schedule(() => {
        
    }, 1)
```

this function receives a callback and the an number that is the time to repeat this callback (it's a repetitive timer function).

All right, this will be scheduled forever until i run the next function.

```
    this.schedule(() => {
        this.unschedule(callback_fn);
    }, 1)
```

unschedule() function receives a callback to stop this schedule, so i should be able to stop the scheduled function in the same callback function refering to this callback.

I can do that:

```
this.schedule( this.callbackSchedule, 1)

private callbackSchedule() {
    console.log("test");
    this.unschedule(this.callbackSchedule);
}
```

that works, it print test once.

## My question

How can I reference to the anonymous callback in one's own callback? it is possible?

Comment: You can have a named function expression, but then it would cause problems with `this`

Answer (score 0):

When you generate an anonymous callback and pass it directly to a function, if you don't save a reference at that time, it's gone and there's no magic way to get a reference later.  You would have to save a reference at the time of creation, e.g.:

```
this.myCallback = () => { /*...*/ };
this.schedule(this.myCallback, 1);

// Later:
this.unschedule(this.myCallback);
```

This doesn't seem any better to me than your approach with `callbackSchedule` defined as a method.

Comment: So, it's not possible?

Comment: I guess not, by your definition of what you want, but as you know, there's an easy workaround.